# Reverse engineering rc transmitter main board with opentx

Tags: c++, embedded, reverse-engineering

So I was wandering through OpenTX code on GitHub and came across stm32f4xx standard peripheral drivers for new Taranis x9e . I know that Taranis xd9 plus uses a stm32f205 mcu, but are those drivers compatible with any Stm32f4xx mcu?. In the file that we could find gpio header files. From that, can we reverse engineer the pin mapping for analog pins, switches, pots, and gimbals, etc.? If so, how? Is there a technique for extracting those data?

Answer (score 0):

The STM32F4xx and STM32f2xx have [separate libraries](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1939), although where peripherals are common across devices, I believe they are compatible (unlike the STM32F1 which differs considerably).

That said; you cannot determine the I/O mapping for a specific *application* from the standard peripheral library; most pins on the STM32 are multiplexed between several functions and each peripheral can be multiplexed between several pins.  Moreover the pin functions between devices and device packages differ considerably in any case.

The simplest way to determine the I/O assignment is via the source code; without that it might be possible to attach a JTAG or SWI debugger and read the I/O registers and the compiled code directly, but it is likely that the debug port is locked-out in production to prevent reverse engineering or IP theft.

If the product is open-source then you can simply ask the manufacturer for the code.  If the product uses open-source libraries with licences that require that all linked code is also open-source (such as GPL) then strictly you also have the right to the source code, but of course unless you see the source code, you cannot easily determine that such code has been incorporated.

Other than that of course, it is possible to determine what devices are attached to which pins with an oscilloscope and a multimeter and some electronics knowledge.  Such attempts however can be  made difficult by the use of multi-layer boards and BGA chip packages, short of X-Raying the board.

If the product is not open-source or open-hardware, then any attempts to reverse engineer it may be illegal, and despite that unfair to the developers whose livelihoods may depend on the protection of in their intellectual property.

Comment: Thank you for your very well described answer.This is an only open-source product so I am trying to it recreate for non-commercial use.I don't think its illegal because they have already ported it to Atmega2560 and its on opentx git as a DIY project. I don't have the hardware but I am trying to map I/O solely through source code.I might as-well just compile  the code and load it to a discovery board and try to identify I/O through a oscilloscope because pins like PPM are easy to identify as they output wave forms.

Comment: @F_A_Q If you have all the code, then you can certainly determine the IO mapping from that, but not from the STM standard peripheral library alone, but rather the code that uses it. You did not mention the availability of any other code, or the availability of code for the specific product of interest.  You might assume programming knowledge here, but not necessarily knowledge of the s/w & h/w you mentioned; some links would help.